# Can't get my React app to fill the screen

Tags: css, reactjs, redux, materialize

No matter what I've tried I cannot get the `#root` div in my react app to fill the whole screen. It will leave a significant portion of space above and to the left of the `#root` tag where all the compiled react code is being displayed.

Here is a link to the repo, I would imagine that the issue lies in the `./public/index.html` file or the `./src/app.js` or `./src/index.js`.

https://github.com/dmshakur/fitness_plan

I've tried to add css styling to the html and body tags, as well as the `#root` tag and the `.app` class that are defaulted when using create-react-app. I've tried using `height` and `width` with both `100vh/vw` and `100%` on both.

I wanted to figure this out on my own, but it just will not work and it is consuming too much time.

Comment: Isn't is because of the padding on body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Culprit is **body** tag. There is a padding of 5em coming on it.
[image]

Culprit file is `src/pages/Welcome/Welcome.css`
you have

```
body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  background: #dadada;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  line-height: 2;
  padding: 5em;
}
```

removing this padding fixes the issue.

```
body {
      display: flex;
      min-height: 100vh;
      flex-direction: column;
      font-size: 62.5%;
      background: #dadada;
      font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
      line-height: 2;
}
```

I will suggest you remove the styling on the body tag directly and make a specific class which you can add to a div.